# Why does passing a parameter pack to a function with one template parameter call it multiple times?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

Take this code:

```
template<typename T>
int foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo called" << std::endl;
    return 10;
};

template<typename... Ts>
std::vector<int> bar(Ts... ts)
{
    std::vector<int> vec{foo<Ts>()...};
    return vec;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = bar(1,2,3,4);
}
```

The code above outputs:

```
foo called
foo called
foo called
foo called
```

How is this possible? I thought I had understood template parameter packs, but how does the line `std::vector<int> vec{foo<Ts>()...};` cause `foo` to be called multiple times? Is `foo` returning a parameter pack, since we use the `...` operator on the function call?

What's going on this code?

Comment: See ["Pack expansion"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion): `"A pattern followed by an ellipsis, in which the name of at least one parameter pack appears at least once, is expanded into zero or more comma-separated instantiations of the pattern, where the name of the parameter pack is replaced by each of the elements from the pack, in order."`.

Comment: `foo<Ts>()...` => `foo<Ts1>(), foo<Ts2>(), foo<Ts3>, etc.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo<T>()...` is expanded to `foo<T1>(), foo<T2>(), foo<T2>(), ...`. In your case, since your vector has four components, your function will be called four times with the expansions.